# OpenWrite Error On Export

Tags: export

I am attempting to search and export records from a very large file (~ 9,640,000 Kb).

To do this I have used the following code:

```
ClearAll;

file = OpenRead["d:\\Fishes.csv"];
Clear[line];

sebastidaeRecords = Reap[While[True,    
    line = ReadLine[file];
    If[SameQ[line, EndOfFile], Break[]];
 
    temp = ImportString[line, "CSV"][[1]];
    If[StringContainsQ[temp[[125]], "Sebastidae"],
    Sow[temp];
    ];
    ];]

    sebastidaerec = Level[sebastidaeRecords[[2]], 2];

    Length[sebastidaerec]
```

I then check to see that a few records in the list sebastidaerec to insure
that the records have the appropriate structure and determine the number of records in the resulting expression sebastidaerec.

I then set the directory to where I want to place the exported file as follows:

```
SetDirectory["D:\\Documents\\Museums\\AustralianMuseumsFromPiscesFile"]
```

Finally, I issue the following command:

```
 Export["Sebastidae.csv", sebastidaerec, "CSV"]
```

However, rather than exporting the file, I receive an Error
"OpenWrite: Cannot open D:\Documents\Museums\AustralianMuseumsFromPicesFile\Sebastidae.csv"

What is confusing me is that I have used this exact code, except for the change in
StringContainsQ[temp[[125]], "Sebastidae"], Sow[temp]; to reflect different names for
different family names (found in the 125th column of the CSV file) and associated variable/file names for records of fishes from other fish families, without any issues.  The search of this file for "Sebastidae" generates 8404 records, but I have about 140 GB of available disk space and a previous search for "Scorpaenidae" generated > 14,000 records without issue.  Attempting to Export only the first thousand records generates the identical error.

The appropriate directory exists (and contains the results of previous runs for different
families obtained without encountering this problem), so that doesn't seem to be the issue.
After exporting (or trying to) I close the file being read using

```
 Close["d:\\Fishes.csv"];
```

After exporting (or trying to) and closing the file being read, the following command returns True indicating that all the records in "Fishes.csv" had been evaluated.

```
 SameQ[line, EndOfFile]
```

Anyone have any idea how to resolve this issue and permit the Export command to work as it
did previously for other family name searches?

Comment: Have you tried to export something else to the file and location you want to use? Random data perhaps, just to check whether the problem is with the data you are trying to export,  or with the location you are trying to export to.

Comment: I also wonder if you have a typo in the code or the error message: note that the error message contains "PICES" and not the more reasonable "PISCES", ie it's missing an S. Is it possible that you had a typo in the Export path?

Comment: Yes, I too noted after posting that I had misspelled Pisces in the posting of the error message, but it is spelled correctly in both the error and the SetDirectory command and there is no failure in opening the directory.  Also I simply used [[1;;1000]] to a new variable "sebastidae1" and subsequently export to a new file ("Sebastidae1.csv", but get the same error.

Comment: Simply using randomdata = RandomWord[500]; followed by Export["randomword.csv",randomdata,"CSV"] also generates the OpenWrite Error.

Comment: It's almost as if a lock on an output stream has been set somehow, but not unlocked prior to my attempt to write.  I was hoping I could figure this out before closing the file, throwing away the results and the rebooting, since it takes about 10-15 hours for the large file to be read and the results produced.

Comment: You could at least DumpSave the results out to a proprietary format, and then reimport them from a fresh kernel after reboot.